# How can I wait for my iframe to load before executing a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form in an iframe. I am submitting that form from a parent window. the server returns an success or failure flag to that iframe. I want to wait for the iframe to get the succcess or failure flag before closing the parent window.

I am trying jquery .ready() but its not working.

I also do not want to put the code below in my iframe's onload with some hacks to close parent window.

```
 document.myFrame.submit(); // a function called submit() inside my iframe that submits a form in the iframe
      $(document.myFrame).ready(function(){
          var successError = document.myFrame.successError
          if(successError == "Y"){
              closeParentWindow();
          }else{
              alert(successError);
          }

      });
```

Comment: I don't know what CORS is so its probably the latter

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document.myFrame).load(function(){
      var successError = document.myFrame.successError
      if(successError == "Y"){
          closeParentWindow();
      }else{
          alert(successError);
      }

  });
```

Raw js example:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.addEventListener('load', function(){ alert('asd'); });
iframe.src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/JRWox-i6aAk";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vKKFJ/)

As you said, it may be cross origin resource sharing issue too

Comment: did not work. I put an alert in it never gets executed. I also tried $("#theframeid")

Comment: @user521180 Is your code inside of `$(document).ready(function () {});`?

Comment: @ian what is inside of ..?